# more than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the above error when I use

```
double x = log10(100);
```

I have used it in other class, in the same project and it does not show this error.

How do I fix it?

Many thanks

Chintan

Comment: I'm assuming your actual implementation takes in a variable as opposed to 100, if not: x = 2..

Comment: Check the libraries you use or the classes you inherit from. Seems like you are having a conflict to call the function. If possible use the class name in order to call the function log10(). This might fix the issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error usually indicates that there is more than one overload for the function `log10` and that none of them is *better* than the others for that particular call. For example, the overloads could take `float` and `double`: `100` is an `int` that can be converted to either and the conversions are equivalent, so the compiler cannot determine what the *best* option is.

You can force the conversion to one of the overloads explicitly:

```
double x = log10( 100. );    // 100. is a double
float  y = log10( 100f );    // 100f is a float
int i = 100;
double z = log10( static_cast<double>(i) ); // or cast
```